Authentication error: app._isFirebaseServerApp is not a function (it is undefined)
I have this Problem in main app but working on another project. When I run the relevant part in app.js alone, it gives the same error (just like in the other project). I use expo. Also my package.json:
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/metro-runtime": "~3.1.3",
    "@firebase/app": "^0.9.29",
    "@firebase/auth": "^1.6.2",
    "@firebase/database": "^1.0.3",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.23.1",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.7.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^18.7.3",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "*",
    "@react-navigation/native": "6.0.0",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.16",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.14",
    "expo": "~50.0.14",
    "expo-constants": "~14.4.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",
    "firebase": "^10.11.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.6",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.4.6",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.6.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-paper": "*",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.3",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
    "react-navigation": "*",
    "react-navigation-stack": "*"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1"
  },
  "private": true
}

problem
When I run the relevant part in app.js alone, it gives the same error (just like in the other project).

while posting a question please avoid posting only image of your code or error logs instead post in text format so that it will be easier for other to go through form their end .

You are mixing use of the Firebase Web Client SDK (firebase) and React-Native-Firebase (@react-native-firebase).  You almost certainly do not want to be doing that.  Here is an article (disclosure: I wrote it) describing the differences.
Additionally, when you install the Firebase Web Client SDK (npm i firebase) you do NOT need to install its sub-components (@firebase/app, @firebase/auth, etc.)
Looking at the stack trace that comes with that error message, you should see where in your own code you are calling an API which leads to that error.  In the future, providing a full stack trace rather than just an error message is way more helpful.  Even more helpful would be for you to track down where in your code the error is being thrown from, and then share with us a snippet of that code.

Thank you for your solution. The problem was that I was using "@firebase/auth" as you said. I solved this by deleting from dependencies and defining "firebase/auth". I tried this before, but I did not delete the component(@firebase/auth).

That is still mixing Firebase Web Client and React Native Firebase.  If your code is not using react-native-firebase then remove all of those dependencies.  If your code imports from both firebase/xxx and react-native-firebase/xxx that is likely not a good situation.  Pick one or the other, as per my writeup above.
